# About the simple problem in Python (Array)

Tags: python, arrays

I am going to make a full chart into Python, like below. The score itself will be provided from the user by using int(input()).

Subject    A   B   C   D   E

Sociology  89  78  98  78  45

Algebra    78  98  65  78  65

English    45  98  45  61  37

into
midterm_score = [[89, 78, 45], [78, 98, 98], [98, 65, 45],[78, 78, 61], [45, 65, 37]]

My code is

```
midterm_score = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
student = [0,0,0]
for i in range (0, 4):
    print("Enter Student " + str(i+1) + "'s Sociology Score: ")
    Soc_score = int(input())
    print("Enter Student " + str(i+1) + "'s Algebra Score: ")
    Alg_score = int(input())
    print("Enter Student " + str(i+1)+"'s English Score: ")
    Eng_score = int(input())
    student[i] = [Soc_score, Alg_score, Eng_score]
midterm_score = [student[0], student[1], student[2], student[3], student[4]]
print(midterm_score)
```

With this code, I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File: "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    student[i] = [Soc_score, Alg_score, Eng_score]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

So, I tried extending the index range like

```
student = [0,0,0,0]
```

and

```
for i in range (0,5)
```

but still makes the same error code again and again.
I would appreciate it if you could teach me how to do it well. I am  a first-time learner of this language.

Comment: Student is len 3 but you are assigning student[3] and student[4]. Y?

Comment: Note that you don't have to pre-allocate the elements of a list. You can `append` as many elements as you want.

Comment: Indexes start from `0`. So if you want to iterate on a list with 4 elements, the last index is `3`. Because `range`'s end is exclusive, you only need `range(0, 4)`. But why bother? You can just do `for i in range(len(your_list))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python `range` is inclusive-exclusive, consider that

```
print(list(range(0,5)))
```

output

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Thus if you want to access indices of list using `range(0,5)` it needs to have at least 5 elements i.e. `student = [0,0,0,0,0]` not `student = [0,0,0,0]`. As side note if first argument you give to range is 0 you might left it, that is:

```
for i in range(0,3):
    print(i)
```

is equivalent to

```
for i in range(3):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

In python, the `range` function returns a sequence of numbers in a determined range. Using `range` with 2 parameters, determines the start and the end of the sequence.

Example:

```py
nums = range(10, 16)
print(nums)
# output: [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

Notice that 10 (the start of the range) was present, but 16 (the end of the range) was not.

Therefore in your code, when `students` is of length of 3, you will need to have the `range` return an indexes list of 3 elements, between 0 and 3, instead of 0 and 4. This will give you `[0, 1, 2]` - the indexes you need. This is because in Python, like most languages, indexes of sequences starts with 0, so the largest index of a list with `n` elements, is `n-1`

Answer (score 0):

Never mind me, just shrinked your code in here

And also try it and tell me if this is what you want...

```py
student = [
    [
     int(input(f"Enter Student {str(i+1)}'s Sociology Score: ")),
     int(input(f"Enter Student {str(i+1)}'s Algebra Score: ")),
     int(input(f"Enter Student {str(i+1)}'s English Score: "))
    ] for i in range(4)] 
    # Gets user input 4 times and appended to student variable

midterm_score = [*student[:4]] # Unpacks list
print(midterm_score)
```

tell me if its okay for you...

Comment: You did shrink the code, but made it much less readable. Short code is less important than readability of the code. Putting everything in one single line with lots of function calls and castings and formatting means less readability.

Answer (score 0):

You are inconsistent in the number of students you want to work with, defining 3 students with `student = [0,0,0]` (or 4 students after changing it to `student = [0,0,0,0]`), then trying to input values for 4 students using `for i in range (0, 4):` and finally, trying to output values for 5 students using `midterm_score = [student[0], student[1], student[2], student[3], student[4]]` whereby `student[4]` is undefined.

As mentioned in other answers, you don't have to predefine lists (arrays) and with this type of tasks, it's safer to begin with an empty list `[]` and append items to it when necessary.

If the number of students to work with is known beforehand, then it's a good idea to use a variable containing this number; for example:

```py
midterm_score = []
student = []
print("Enter number of students:")
nr_students = int(input())
for i in range (nr_students):
    print("Enter Student " + str(i+1) + "'s Sociology Score: ")
    Soc_score = int(input())
    print("Enter Student " + str(i+1) + "'s Algebra Score: ")
    Alg_score = int(input())
    print("Enter Student " + str(i+1)+"'s English Score: ")
    Eng_score = int(input())
    student.append([Soc_score, Alg_score, Eng_score])
    midterm_score.append(student[i])
print(midterm_score)
```

If you *don't know* the number of students beforehand, you can use the following code that will stop on any non-integer input:

```py
midterm_score = []
student = []
nr_students = 5
i = 0
while True:
    try:
        print("Enter Student " + str(i+1) + "'s Sociology Score: ")
        Soc_score = int(input())
        print("Enter Student " + str(i+1) + "'s Algebra Score: ")
        Alg_score = int(input())
        print("Enter Student " + str(i+1)+"'s English Score: ")
        Eng_score = int(input())
        student.append([Soc_score, Alg_score, Eng_score])
        midterm_score.append(student[i])
        i += 1
    except ValueError:
        break
print(midterm_score)
```

The `while True:`-loop can theoretically loop endlessly. But as soon as the user inputs any non-integer, `int(input())` will throw a `ValueError` exception. We catch this exception using `except ValueError:` and specify that in this case, the `while`-loop has to break.